# Get the top 3 elements of a Django nested query

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Using django with a MySQL DB and given these **models**:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    .
    .
    .
    author = models.ForeignKey('Account', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    reactions = models.ManyToManyField('Reaction', through="PostReaction", related_name='reactions', blank=True)

class Account(AbstractUser):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)

class PostReaction(models.Model):
    reaction = models.ForeignKey('Reaction', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    reacted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )

class Reaction(models.Model):
    reaction_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    reaction_url = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    reaction_category = models.ForeignKey('ReactionCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**View** for a list of published posts :

```
class PostListView(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset= Post.objects.filter(is_publish = True).select_related('author').prefetch_related('tags','reactions')    

    serializer_class = PostListReadSerializer
```

**Serialisers** to produce a JSON list of posts:

```
class TagListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'

class PostShortReactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Reaction
        fields = ["reaction_name", "reaction_url", "id"]

class PostAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ["username", "avatar"]

class PostListReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    reactions = PostShortReactionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    author = PostAccountSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields='__all__'
```

Tried to form a subquery to retrieve the required data, but the query is not executed in the output:

**Option one:**

```
sq= Subquery(PostReaction.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('id')).values_list('id', flat=True)[:3]) 

subquery = PostReaction.objects.filter(post=68).values('reaction__id').annotate(reaction_count=Count('reaction__id')).order_by('-reaction_count')[:3]

queryset = Post.objects.filter(is_publish = True).select_related('author').prefetch_related('tags', Prefetch('reactions', queryset=PostReaction.objects.filter(post=sq)))
```

**In the second option**, grouping fails (naturally) and outputs rows that differ only in response, but adding [:3] at the end slices the data across the whole query.

**Option two:**

```
queryset= Post.objects.filter(is_publish = True).select_related('author').prefetch_related('tags','reactions').annotate(reactions_count = Count('reactions__id')).order_by('-reactions_count')
```

*The Reaction field in the JSON response should contain the top 3 reactions to the post*, sorted by the number of reactions left under the post.An approximate structure should look like this:

```
{
  "id": 68,
  "tags": [
            {
             "id": 1,
             "name": "Xxx",
             "slug": "xxx"
             }...
            ],
   "reactions": [
                  {
                   "reaction_name": "xxx",
                    "reaction_url": "xxx",
                    "id": 1
                },
                {
                    "reaction_name": "xxx2",
                    "reaction_url": "xxx2",
                    "id": 2
                },
                {
                    "reaction_name": "xxx3",
                    "reaction_url": "xxx3",
                    "id":3
                },
         
   "author": {
               "username": "xxx",
               "avatar": "xxx"
             },
  *....Other post's data....*           
 },
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @itprorh66
The task is that I need to output the top 3 reactions to each post. One post may have multiple reactions with the same id from different users. The top 3 should be a grouping of reactions by id and a slice of the first three from the list according to the rule: from more people who left a reaction to fewer. When using the queryset specified in the question body (option 2), grouping and slicing does not work (the posts are clipped, not the reactions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SerializerMethodField for this.

```
class PostListReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    reactions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    author = PostAccountSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields='__all__'
    
    def get_reactions(self, obj):
        # here get the necessary records, but be careful with n+1
        objs = PostReaction.objects.filter(post=obj).values('reaction__id').annotate(reaction_count=Count('reaction__id')).order_by('-reaction_count')[:3]
        return PostShortReactionSerializer(objs, many=True).data
```